# Rails Vuejs Webpacker: Passing instance variable data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vuejs2, instance-variables, webpacker

I am trying to learn how to build an app with Rails 5.1 with Vuejs, as generated via the Webpacker gem.

```
$ rails new myvueapp --webpack=vue
```

How do I pass instance variable data back an forth between the Vue components, to get my data in/out of the database?

Let's say for example that I have a User model with Username and Email fields.   Is there a simple example of how to pass instance variable, @user, data from the controller to a component?

I believe there are two ways to do this:

(1) In the controller, has the `render :json => @user` and then use something like the fetch API or Axios to retrieve the data in the .vue component.

-or-

(2) Use the something like the example `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'hello_vue' %>` together with a `<%= content_tag ... %>` in a view.

When I do this `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'hello_vue' %>` example, I can see the "Hello Vue!" from the data in the component "message" variable, but am having trouble finding an example of instance variable data, eg: @user data, being passed in and out of Rails.

Any examples of how to pass @user data would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Passing between Vue components? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch or take a look at Vuex for complex state management. 

Passing between Vue frontend and Rails backend using a httpclient like axios and a standard rails api.

Comment: Thanks, but not what I'm looking for.  I'm not looking to pass data between Vue components.  I'm looking to pass data from the Rails the database manage by Rails (via model & controller) to the Vue component, now integrated into Rails.

Answer (score 2):

I did something that works but I don't really like: create a method in the `window` scope like:

```js
// app/javascript/packs/some_app.js

window.someAppPack = function (var1, var2) {
  // ...
  new Vue({
    // ...
    data () {
      return {
        var1,
        var2,
      }
    }
    // ...
  })
}
```

And in the Rails template:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'somePack' %>

<script>
  someAppPack(#{raw @var1.to_json}, #{raw @var2.to_json})
</script>
```

This seems dirty to me, and I'm wondering the benefits :

- Vue apps should be reactive, so the data *may* be updated sometime, and a call to a JSON resource will be made. Which makes passing original data pointless.
- if Vue is only used to make some portions of the page reactive, why use all the webpack stuff when we can use "inline" Vue with standard Rails pipeline ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I can think of two ways to do this.

1. Use `v-model` on a form.  Whatever value is retrieved or updated will immediately be usable in your Vue instance. (e.g. `<%= f.input :username, input_html: { 'v-model': 'username' } %>`
2. Use data attributes.  Let's say you have a controller that has a `@user` variable.

Then in your view, you could do something like (this may not be 100% correct as its just from memory):

```
<% simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :username, input_html: { id: 'user_username', data: { username: @user.username } } %>
  <%= f.input :email, input_html: { id: 'user_email', data: { email: @user.email } } %>
<% end %>
```

Then you can use JavaScript to access the data attributes.  In these examples since both are forms, it would be preferable to use `v-model`, but you could use data attributes for non-form stuff.  For example, I frequently use data attributes for the URI used in an AJAX request that may differ from test site to production etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've had the same issue, however a props helped me.

app/views/**/*.html.erb

```
<div id="app" data-initial-value="#{raw(html_escape(@var.to_json))}"></div>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'app' %>
```

app/javascript/packs/app.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from '../app.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const app = new Vue({
        render: h => h(App, {
            props:{
                value: JSON.parse(document.querySelector("#app").dataset.initialValue)
            }
        })
    }).$mount()
    document.body.appendChild(app.$el)
})
```

app/javascript/app.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
  {{ value.content }}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  name: "App",
  props: {
    value: Object
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this job by using gem [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon/issues)'s power.

1. in a controller

```rb
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = User.first
    gon.user = @user
  end
end
```

2. the in layout:

```rb
# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= Gon::Base.render_data %>
```

3. in webpacker's entry file

```js
// app/javascript/packs/hello_vue.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import HelloVue from '../views/HelloVue.vue'

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const app = new Vue({
    el: document.getElementById('div-you-want-to-mount'),
    components: { HelloVue },
    render: h => h(HelloVue, { props: gon })
  }).$mount()
})
```

4. in HelloVue.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="hello">
    User: {{ user }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['user']
}
</script>
```